# Requesting camera permissions results in NullPointerException in String.equals

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to request camera permissions to use Google OCR in my Android app, but on most devices it crashes on install.

I've read similar posts that say this is caused by a null context being passed into `ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission()`, but I can't see how the context would be null.

Here is my code:

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder builder = new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder();
    StrictMode.setVmPolicy(builder.build());

    surfaceView = findViewById(R.id.surfaceView);

    if (checkForPermissions(Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            Manifest.permission.INTERNET)) {
        surfaceView.getHolder().addCallback(new SurfaceCallback());
    }
}
...
private boolean checkForPermissions(String ... permissions) {
    List<String> permissionsToRequest = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(permissions));

    for (Iterator<String> it = permissionsToRequest.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, it.next()) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            it.remove();
        }
    }
    if (permissionsToRequest.isEmpty()) {
        return true;
    }

    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, permissionsToRequest.toArray(permissions), 0);
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                       @NonNull int[] results) {
    if (requestCode != 0) {
        return;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        if (results[i] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && permissions[i] != null) {
            AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).create();
            alertDialog.setTitle("Permissions needed");
            alertDialog.setMessage("This app requires camera permissions to function properly.");
            alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "OK",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                                    new String[] {
                                        Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
                                        Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                                        Manifest.permission.INTERNET
                                    },
                                    0);
                        }
                    });
            alertDialog.show();
            return;
        }
    }
    surfaceView.getHolder().addCallback(new SurfaceCallback());
}
```

`SurfaceCallback` implements `SurfaceHolder.Callback` and that's where the camera is actually initialized.

This is the exception:

```
4606/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.google.android.packageinstaller, PID: 4606
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.google.android.packageinstaller/com.android.packageinstaller.permission.ui.GrantPermissionsActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
at com.android.packageinstaller.permission.ui.GrantPermissionsActivity.computePermissionGrantState(GrantPermissionsActivity.java:314)
at com.android.packageinstaller.permission.ui.GrantPermissionsActivity.updateDefaultResults(GrantPermissionsActivity.java:363)
at com.android.packageinstaller.permission.ui.GrantPermissionsActivity.onCreate(GrantPermissionsActivity.java:122)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6662)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
```

Comment: Your problem is inside of a `computePermissionGrantState()`, which is not shown in your question's source code.

Comment: @CommonsWare Forgive my ignorance, but I'm not even sure how to get to that code. By that I mean it's Android's code that I can't just click on from logcat.

Comment: Sorry, I was misreading the stack trace, focusing too much on the class and not enough on the package. Let me putter through the source code and see if I can identify what might be wrong.

Comment: One thing that you can fix: get rid of `Manifest.permission.INTERNET` from your `checkForPermissions()` call, as that is not a `dangerous` permission.

Comment: The issue is with the `toArray` in `checkForPermissions` -  see List doc: If the list fits in the specified array with room to spare (i.e., the array has more elements than the list), the element in the array immediately following the end of the list is set to null.  Most likely it is a case where you pruned the original list by at least 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By looking at the source code, my best guess is that you are winding up with `null` as one of the entries in the `String[]` that you are passing to `ActivityCompat.requestPermissions()`.

That might be due to something with how you are converting between arrays and lists. In particular, `permissionsToRequest.toArray(permissions)` is kinda scary, as you are trying to reuse a `String[]` that is passed in as a parameter. Plus, [as Andy pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53992172/requesting-camera-permissions-results-in-nullpointerexception-in-string-equals/53992295#comment94822192_53992172), `toArray()` sets unused array elements to `null`.

I'd allocate a fresh `String[]`, as I do [here](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/blob/v8.13/Camera/CameraKit/app/src/main/java/com/commonsware/android/camera/AbstractPermissionActivity.java#L89-L105):

```
  private boolean hasPermission(String perm) {
    return(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, perm)==
      PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
  }

  private String[] netPermissions(String[] wanted) {
    ArrayList<String> result=new ArrayList<String>();

    for (String perm : wanted) {
      if (!hasPermission(perm)) {
        result.add(perm);
      }
    }

    return(result.toArray(new String[result.size()]));
  }
```

Comment: @C.Swainston: Ideally, `ActivityCompat.requestPermissions()` would do some sanity-checking on the inputs, so you'd fail with a better error message. I [filed a feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/122163323) for that. Glad to hear that you got it working!